# Module not found error Kivy Python 3.6 Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Getting an error that Kivy module is not found after installing Kivy for Python 3.6 using pip3 and brew.

Please advise.

Comment: What is the Cython version that was installed?

Comment: This is fixed now, I installed PyGame too. that was missing from the installation steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip3 install pygame

Installing pygame and setting the PATH correctly fixed this issue.